# Delete duplicate rows from big table by column value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Got big table (~1.6m rows), which looks like:

```
------------------------------------
| id |   text   | image_id | order |
------------------------------------
|  2 |  random  |    12    |   1   |
------------------------------------
|  3 |  random  |    12    |   2   |
------------------------------------
|  5 |  random  |    12    |   1   |
------------------------------------
|  6 |  random  |    12    |   2   |
------------------------------------
|  8 |  random  |    17    |   1   |
------------------------------------
|  9 |  random  |    17    |   1   |
------------------------------------
```

The goal is to have:

```
------------------------------------
| id |   text   | image_id | order |
------------------------------------
|  2 |  random  |    12    |   1   |
------------------------------------
|  3 |  random  |    12    |   2   |
------------------------------------
|  8 |  random  |    17    |   1   |
------------------------------------
```

Many rows with different ids but other data is the same, so we need to keep only one row of each order number (111222333444 need to be 1234).

This query is working for small tables:

```
DELETE n1 FROM table n1, table n2 WHERE image_id = 12 AND n1.id > n2.id AND n1.order = n2.order
```

But for big tables query takes too long, so receive timeout.

DB Backend is Laravel & PHP, and we use chunks to query this tables.

Basically goal is to crawl through big table based on image_id and remove duplicates so for each image_id we got rows with order columns like: 1,3,4,5,6,7,8 etc.

Comment: that delete query needs indexing on (image_id, id, order) column

Answer (score 0):

Just use `unique()` method from laravel

```
$uniqueData = Model::unique(function ($item) {
   return $item['image_id'].$item['order'];
});
$uniqueData->values()->all();
return $uniqueData;
```